# add controller link to top links through module xml file Magento

Tags: xml, magento, hyperlink, module

HI i have create a test module in magento and now i want to add its link in the top links

the xml file of module is

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>

          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <routeurfrontend_index_index>

           <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc" template="afficher.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_index>
</layout>
```

> and the link of my controller is something like
>
> ```
> http:/localhost/mage/index.php/test/index/
> ```
>
> now i want to add a link in the top link with the name of test

please suggest what should i do in the ml file

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="" name="">

        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: What is the URL of your link ?

Comment: <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="YOUR MODULE NAME"><label>YOUR CUSTOM LABEL</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl (SIMILLAR YOUR URL)"/><title>YOUR CUSTOM LABEL</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own link using below code in top links. Change as you need it.

```
<reference name="root">
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>example</label>
        <url helper="moduleName/getIndexUrl" />
        <title>example</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/> 
        <position>100</position>
        <liParams/>
        <aParams>class="top-link-example"</aParams>
        <beforeText></beforeText>
        <afterText></afterText>
    </action>
</reference>
</reference>
```

In your **Helper/Data.php** create like below

```
class YourNameSpace_ModuleName_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

const ROUTE_TEST_INDEX = 'moduleName/controllerName/actionName'; //for example 'customer/account/login'

public function getIndexUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl(self::ROUTE_TEST_INDEX);
    }


}
```

Comment: can anybody tell me how can i get base url in xml file

Comment: Use this `<urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />`

Comment: HI i don’t want to add static url http://yourexample.com in xml please suggest how  can i achieve this dynamically

Comment: That was just an example. What URL you want to add ?

Comment: i just want   mysiteurl/test    like 
http:/localhost/mage/index.php/test/index/

Comment: or can i concatinate some thing with this  core/url/getHomeUrl   like  core/url/getHomeUrl/test

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52380/discussion-between-rohit-goel-and-slimshadddyyy)